# How to add a column with values depending on existing rows with lower index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a fast way of adding a column to a data frame `df` with values depending on all the rows of `df` with smaller index? A very simple example where the new column only depends on the value of one other column would be `df["new_col"] = df["old_col"].cumsum()` (if `df` is ordered), but I have something more complicated in mind. Ideally, I'd like to write something like

`df["new_col"] = df.[some function here](f)`,

where `[some function]` sets the `i`-th value of `df["new_col"]` to `f(df[df.index <= df.index[i]])`. (Ideally `[some function]` can also be applied to `groupby()` objects.)

At the moment I loop through rows, add a temporary column containing a dict of relevant values and then apply a function, but this is very slow, memory-inefficient, etc.

Comment: Why do you need a temporary row? Couldn't you just pass a slice up to n-1 to your function? I think you won't get around a loop.

Comment: Oops, this was a typo: I meant to write that I added a temporary column where the `i`-th entry stores the information needed to compute the `i`-th value of `df["new_col"]` so that I can just use `.apply(f, axis=1)` to create the new column.

Comment: Shame. I just thought there might be a nice pandas function I overlooked since we can also compute conceptually similar (albeit simpler) stuff like `cumsum()` without a loop.

Comment: I think adding a temporary column adds a lot of overhead, can't you calculate it on the original Series? I think cumsum is different, because you can reuse the previous values.

Comment: I'd like to keep this temporary column since I expect these results to be reused.